# Playwright config file not using all of the values set

Tags: typescript, playwright

My Playwright config file doesn't appear to be used properly. When I run my `test` command, I make sure to point to my config file (named: `playwright.config.ts`, using `--config`) and the terminal verifies that this file is being used.

However, the only the `retries` setting appears to work. Timeouts setting changes are not applied and screenshots are not generated after tests whether its set to "on" or "only-on-failure". A folder is not generated without the `outputDir` set either.

TypeScript has not made any error on my config file so I can't tell whats wrong. The config file is located in the same folder as my tests, it is not at the root.

I moved the file outside to the root and had the same issue.

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: 'tests', //is recognized
  timeout: 45000,
  retries: 1, //is recognized
  outputDir: './screenshots',
  use: {
    headless: false,
    viewport: { width: 1440, height: 800 },
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
  },
};

export default config;
```

Here are the docs for reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

me too faced with this problem, my mistake was in using `test` method:

```
import { firefox } from 'playwright';
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

    test('test not using configuration', async () => {
        var browser = await firefox.launch()
        var context = await browser.newContext()
        var page = await browser.newPage()
         
        await page.goto("http://ya.ru")
        page.waitForLoadState()
        var input = await page.waitForSelector('#text');
        (await input).click
        await page.keyboard.type('test text', {delay: 100})
        console.log(await page.video()?.path())
    })
```

that code not using configuration because there was initialize new browser with default parameters.

that example of code with using configuration:

```
test('test using configuration', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("http://ya.ru")
    page.waitForLoadState()
    var input = await page.waitForSelector('#text');
    (await input).click
    await page.keyboard.type('test text', {delay: 100})
    console.log(await page.video()?.path())
});
```

that working because we add `page` argument in test method and he was initialize from config file.That example have on [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-configuration/#local-configuration)